# Send integer value from form to another visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am making a game with score but i cant send the score from the first form to the second one
The score start with 1000
When the user play it decrease 
How to send the value after it decrease to a label in form2

Comment: `otherform.somelabel.text = (260).ToString`

Comment: Pass it in your constructor...

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to see - I would guess that your issue is that forms don't have a reference of some sort to each other.

I would suggest making a module (and put it in a Namespace):

```
Namespace MyModule

    Module Module1
        Public f1 as Form1
        Public f2 as Form2

        Public Sub setScore() as String
            ' This assumes Form1 has a public variable playerScore,
            ' and Form2 has a label scoreLabel
            f2.scoreLabel.Text = f1.playerScore
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Second step to this is to make sure in both of your forms, you set the references in the module to that form (example below for Form1 done in the Load event). Be sure that both f1 and f2 have been defined, otherwise you will get a null reference exception when you try to call setScore().

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyModule.f1 = Me
    ' ... and the rest of your code in form load
End Sub
```

Lastly, when your score changes, just call the setScore() sub in MyModule

```
playerScore += 1 'example

MyModule.setScore() ' update the label in Form2
```